# How to use an API package within ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use the package called "youtube-music-api", however I can't get it to work within React. The code resides within a React component that triggers it when the component mounts. The code I used is as follows:

```
const YoutubeMusicApi = require('youtube-music-api')

function fetchResults(data) {
    const api = new YoutubeMusicApi()
    api.initalize()
    .then(info => {
        api.getSearchSuggestions(data).then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    })
}
```

However, it ends up failing when I try to run it, I receive the following:

[image]

I tried using the package outside of React, and it performed successfully. So, I suspect that the issue may be because with React I am serving the page to the user where they then perform the API call. How might I go about using the package within React?

Comment: You cannot use this package in react(default youtube music domain blocks requests from other domains - CORS). It can be used only in node environments. See the code related to it in the GitHub https://github.com/emresenyuva/youtube-music-api/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the [faker.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) package. you can easily get fake data according your use case.

```
import faker from 'faker'
const [data,setData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
var randomName = faker.name.findName(); // Rowan Nikolaus
var randomEmail = faker.internet.email(); // Kassandra.Haley@erich.biz
var randomCard = faker.helpers.createCard(); // {avatar , name etc..}
setData({ name : randomName , email : randomEmai , card : ...randomCard })
},[]);
```

Comment: What makes you think that fake data will work for the OP’s use case? Their existing code is trying to get real data from YouTube.

Comment: sorry I think you want package for devlopment phase.

Comment: Why would they? That just means they would waste time developing against an API with a different shape, so when it came time to put it in production they'd still have the problem they have no but would have also wasted a bunch of time.